# NASA design handbooks and specifications

Tags: nasa, crewed-spaceflight, spacecraft, reference-request, uncrewed-spaceflight

Does anybody know the designations, publication names, etc. for the design standards which NASA uses for space flight hardware?  I’d like to add these resources into my engineering library.

Answer (score 6):

A search on NASA NTRS for "[design standards](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search?q=design%20standards)" turns up a lot...

[image]

Comment: Very nice!  I’ll check it out!